# How to open react component in new tab without rendering the whole app component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom V6. I want to open a `Gallery` component from a component named `Art` with a Button.
I am trying with `<Link to="/gallery" target="_blank">"a button inside"</Link>`

But when I click `Button` whole `App` rendering in new tab with my `Gallery` component.
Same is happening with `windows.open` and `<a> tag`.

I want to open only the `Gallery` component.
How to do that?

Comment: Your React necessarily needs to load in the new window so it can render your `Gallery` component.

Answer (score 0):

New tab is a new window therefore React needs to load whole page. As an alternative you can show `Gallery` component on the same tab, for example, using Modal component (if you need visual highlight).

Comment: That was like my last option. I was wondering is there any other way. Actually in my gallery component I also have a model component to view the particular art. I don't want to open a popup window on another one lmao...unless there is no other options.

Answer (score 0):

`target="_blank"` causes the browser to open the link in a new tab. Just remove it:

```
<Link to="/gallery">"a button inside"</Link>
```